# What is the exact purpose of the CommandLineRunner in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would appreciate a lot if someone could explain why a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner as well quite often. From what I have read Spring Boot will automatically call the run method of all beans implementing this interface after the application context has been loaded. So run() method is run between the first and the last instructions present in the main() method after beans have been registered. Then what is the specific need to implement CommandLineRunner, I mean why not just to add code from the run() to the main()

Comment: `main` is a static method that doesn't have dependencies injected.

Answer (score 2):

CommandLineRunner is an interface that has run() method. Which is used to execute some code just after the spring boot application has started. The main application should implement this interface and override its run method. In this run method, we write code like initializing our database with some value or any other logic which should be executed just after the app starts.

Comment: what exactly is the moment when spring boot application has started?
if one logs instructions in the main and run methods, he will see that those of the run are executed before the main finished - it makes me think that sentence "after the spring boot application has started" is not correct.
and I wonder why not to initialize the database right in the main method?
what else is it capable to do besides this typical line SpringApplication.run(<Application.class>, args)?